# Sans-serif math with latex in matplotlib

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib

The following script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.rc('font', family='sans-serif')
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.text(0.2,0.5,r"Math font: $451^\circ$")
ax.text(0.2,0.7,r"Normal font (except for degree symbol): 451$^\circ$")

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

is an attempt to use a sans-serif font in matplotlib with LaTeX. The issue is that the math font is still a serif font (as indicated by the axis numbers, and as demonstrated by the labels in the center). Is there a way to set the math font to also be sans-serif?

Comment: You may want to check out https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz. Also, matplotlib was recently equipped with a TikZ/PGF backend, cf. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/319.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958485/matplotlib-not-using-latex-font-while-tex-usetex-true/17967324?noredirect=1#17967324

Comment: does my answer below work?

Answer (score 32):

I always have `text.usetex = True` in my matplotlibrc file. In addition to that, I use this as well:

```
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
       r'\usepackage{siunitx}',   # i need upright \micro symbols, but you need...
       r'\sisetup{detect-all}',   # ...this to force siunitx to actually use your fonts
       r'\usepackage{helvet}',    # set the normal font here
       r'\usepackage{sansmath}',  # load up the sansmath so that math -> helvet
       r'\sansmath'               # <- tricky! -- gotta actually tell tex to use!
]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get the (keyword:) Helvetica font working with matplotlib/pylab in my plots. And I have tried quite a few things! Hopefully google will index this incase others try to do the same.

Comment: Perfect. For more font options, look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html and replace the '\usepackage{helvet}' with your favourite :)

Comment: For an alternate syntax using keyword arguments, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453758/8622053

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to use matplotlib's internal TeX, e.g.:

```
import pylab as plt
params = {'text.usetex': False, 'mathtext.fontset': 'stixsans'}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

If you use an external LaTeX, you can use, e.g., CM Bright fonts:

```
params = {'text.usetex': True, 
          'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{cmbright}', r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Note, that the CM Bright font is non-scalable, and you'll not be able to save PDF/PS!
Same with other options with external LaTeX I've found so far.

Comment: How can I remove italic shape using matplotlib's internal TeX ?

Comment: How did anyone thing it would be a good idea to make italic the standard??

Comment: Italic is a standard for typesetting math.

Comment: This seems to leave some characters, e.g. `$\rho$`, in the standard math font. Any way to fix?

Answer (score 2):

This will enable you to use the Computer Modern Sans font if you, as I, prefer it over Helvetica:

```
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True 
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}']
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'cm'
```

Comment: This worked for me, and I'd been struggling to find what the computer modern fonts were called in the backend. I couldn't find a list anywhere.