# Type 1 fonts with log graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Matplotlib graphs as part of a camera-ready
submission, and the publishing house requires the use of Type 1 fonts
only.

I'm finding that the PDF backend happily outputs Type-1 fonts for
simple graphs with linear Y axes, but outputs Type-3 fonts for
logarithmic Y axes.

Using a logarithmic yscale incurs the use of mathtext, which seems to
use Type 3 fonts, presumably because of the default use of exponential
notation.  I can use an ugly hack to get around this - using
pyplot.yticks() to force the axis ticks to not use exponents - but
this would require moving the plot region to accommodate large labels
(like 10 ^ 6) or writing the axes as 10, 100, 1K, etc. so they fit.

I've tested the example below with the
matplotlib master branch as of today, as well as 1.1.1, which produces
the same behavior, so I don't know that this is a bug, probably just
unexpected behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Simple program to test for type 1 fonts. 
# Generate a line graph w/linear and log Y axes.

from matplotlib import rc, rcParams

rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
#rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['computer modern sans serif']})

# These lines are needed to get type-1 results:
# http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.com/2010/07/type-1-fonts-and-matplotlib-figures.html
rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
rcParams['text.usetex'] = False

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

YSCALES = ['linear', 'log']

def plot(filename, yscale):
    plt.figure(1)
    xvals = range(1, 2)
    yvals = xvals
    plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
    plt.yscale(yscale)
    plt.savefig(filename + '.pdf')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for yscale in YSCALES:
        plot('linegraph-' + yscale, yscale)
```

Does anyone know a clean way to get Type 1 fonts with log axes?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for awareness, this was also posted on the mpl-users mailinglist: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Type-1-fonts-with-log-graphs-tt39606.html

Comment: Some useful references (no answer to this question in them): http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Type-1-font-in-figures-needed-td10294.html & http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/type-1-fonts-and-matplotlib-figures.html

Answer (score 10):

This is the code I use for camera-ready submissions:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def SetPlotRC():
    #If fonttype = 1 doesn't work with LaTeX, try fonttype 42.
    plt.rc('pdf',fonttype = 1)
    plt.rc('ps',fonttype = 1)

def ApplyFont(ax):

    ticks = ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()

    text_size = 14.0

    for t in ticks:
        t.set_fontname('Times New Roman')
        t.set_fontsize(text_size)

    txt = ax.get_xlabel()
    txt_obj = ax.set_xlabel(txt)
    txt_obj.set_fontname('Times New Roman')
    txt_obj.set_fontsize(text_size)

    txt = ax.get_ylabel()
    txt_obj = ax.set_ylabel(txt)
    txt_obj.set_fontname('Times New Roman')
    txt_obj.set_fontsize(text_size)

    txt = ax.get_title()
    txt_obj = ax.set_title(txt)
    txt_obj.set_fontname('Times New Roman')
    txt_obj.set_fontsize(text_size)
```

The fonts won't appear until you run `savefig`

Example:

```
import numpy as np

SetPlotRC()

t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(t)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Signal")
plt.title("Sine Wave")

ApplyFont(plt.gca())
plt.savefig("sine.pdf")
```

Comment: I just tried it with a log-axis. It seems to work for me. Sorry this answer is so late. Hope your paper submission went well! I've been there too.

Answer (score 5):

The preferred method to get Type 1 fonts via matplotlib seems to be to use TeX for typesetting. Doing so results in *all* axis being typeset in the default math font, which is typically undesired but which can be avoided by using TeX-commands.

Long story short, I found this solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np

mp.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True #Let TeX do the typsetting
mp.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sansmath}', r'\sansmath'] #Force sans-serif math mode (for axes labels)
mp.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif' # ... for regular text
mp.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Helvetica, Avant Garde, Computer Modern Sans serif' # Choose a nice font here

fig = mp.figure()
dim = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]

ax = fig.add_axes(dim)
ax.text(0.001, 0.1, 'Sample Text')
ax.set_xlim(10**-4, 10**0)
ax.set_ylim(10**-2, 10**2)
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_xlabel('$\mu_0$ (mA)')
ax.set_ylabel('R (m)')
t = np.arange(10**-4, 10**0, 10**-4)
y = 10*t

mp.plot(t,y)

mp.savefig('tmp.png', dpi=300)
```

Then results in this
[image: resulting image]

Inspired by:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709149/4189024 and
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me, but the following did:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

params = {'pdf.fonttype': 42}
pylab.rcParams.update(params)
```