# Matplotlib greek symbols differ in show() and savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a simple greek letter mu to display in roman font in a saved figure with matplotlib.  I have tried two methods:

1. `plt.xlabel(u'Wavelength (\u03bc m)')`

This method works fine when I do a `show()`, but when I try to use `savefig()`, the mu character shows as a rectangle when saved as a .png.  If I save as a .pdf, the symbol is missing entirely.

2. `plt.xlabel(r'Wavelength ($\mathrm{\mu}$m)')`

This method renders a greek letter with both `show()` and `savefig()`, but the character is still in italics in each case, despite requesting a roman font.

What's the trick?

Comment: I solved the very same problem using the LaTeX package `upgreek`, which provides the macro `\upmu` that I use in matplotlib and in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very good experience with having *all* text (regular and math) beeing typeset by LaTeX. Just set your rc-settings accordingly before plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True #Let TeX do the typsetting
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sansmath}',r'\sansmath']
#Force sans-serif math mode
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif' # ... for regular text
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Helvetica' # Choose a nice font here
```

You can then simply say:

```
plt.xlabel('Wavelength ($\mu$)')
```

Inspired by my own answer here:
[Type 1 fonts with log graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132194/type-1-fonts-with-log-graphs/30309294#30309294)