# How do I get 'matplotlib' to use my LaTeX sans font by default

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to generate figures using `matplotlib` in which all of the text is sans-serif (Open Sans) by default. A number of questions here on SO, along with the Open Sans documentation, suggest something like

```
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
    r'\usepackage[default,scale=0.85]{opensans}'
]
```

should work, but instead I see the serif font. For example, the above uses what looks like Computer Modern, and

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
    r'\usepackage[charter,expert,euro]{mathdesign}',
    r'\usepackage[default,scale=0.85]{opensans}'
]
```

uses Charter. Adding something like `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` has no effect.

How do I force `matplotlib` using LaTeX, to use a specified sans-serif font by default for all text (axes, labels, annotations, etc.)?

---

FWIW, when I don't use LaTeX (`text.usetex=False`) I [don't get Open Sans as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20722904/656912) either, but I do get the sans-serif. For example

```
font = {'family': 'sans-serif', 'sans-serif': ['Open Sans','sans-serif']}
plt.rc('font', **font)
```

results in a sans-serif font that's not Open Sans. I have no problems with Open Sans in other tools or applications, including LaTeX/TeX tools.

Comment: does this help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537868/sans-serif-math-with-latex-in-matplotlib/20709149#20709149 ?