# Antialiased text rendering in matplotlib pgf backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, pdf-generation, pgf

I have a question regarding the text rendering in the matplotlib `pgf` backend. I am using matplotlib to export .pdf files of my plots. In the section with the rcParameters I define that I want to use sans-serif and I want to use Helvetica as font. Therefore I disabled the option `text.usetex`. Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import os

mpl.use('pgf')

pgf_with_latex = {                     
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",       
    "text.usetex": False,                
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Helvetica",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",    
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",       
        r"\usepackage{textcomp}",
        r"\usepackage{sfmath}",
    ]
    }
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def newfig():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    return fig, ax

fig, ax = newfig()
ax.set_xlabel("Some x-label text")
ax.text(0.3, 0.5, r"This text is not antialiased! 0123456789", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=8)
plt.savefig(os.getcwd() + "/test.pdf")
```

The result is, that the tick labels and the text are rendered in Computer Modern (-> LaTeX) instead of Helvetica and they are not rendered as vector graphic and look pixelated. Now, when I enable `text.usetex` the tick labels become vector graphics (I can zoom in without seeing pixels), but the text doesn't!

What do I have to do to get everything (tick labels, axis labels, legend, text etc.) to be vectorized Helvetica? Is that even possible? If not, how do I get text, legend, etc. to be vectorized in Computer Modern like the tick labels?

Edit: Python 3.4.4, matplotlib 1.5.2

here are the smooth tick labels vs. the ragged xlabel
[image: Zoom]

Another edit: If I save my file as .eps instead of .pdf and enable `usextex` I get wonderfully vectorized fonts, but the tick labels are in serif font :<

Comment: I just copied and executed the provided code and everything (including the "This text is not antialiased! 0123456789" string) is vectorized in the generated PDF generated on my machine...

Comment: [Did you zoom in?](https://i.imgur.com/kTZ5zSb.png) This is what it looks like on my machine (the 0.4 is from the x-tick labels, antialiased. The xlabel on the other hand is not).

Comment: Yes I zoomed in. [here is my generated test.pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6a4bvsdhpavhtwp/test.pdf?dl=1), feel free to give a look.

Comment: Curious. Any idea what the reason that it doesn't work for me could be? Any system font issues? I am on Windows 7 btw.

Comment: I have no precise Idea, it may come from your latex install but I'm just guessing. I used Python 2.7.12, matplotlib 1.5.2 and texlive distribution with pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found my answer after many attempts. I found it in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709149/5528308).

I merely added this to the preamble:

```
r'\usepackage{helvet}',    # set the normal font here
r'\usepackage{sansmath}',  # load up the sansmath so that math -> helvet
r'\sansmath'               # <- tricky! -- gotta actually tell tex to use!
```

and set `"text.usetex": False"`. Now it finally uses Helvetica everywhere and it is vectorized everywhere.. well, except for axes with logarithmic scaling. There I have to manually set axis labels by using `ax.set_yticklabels([1, 2, 3, 4])`.