# Upright mu with sans serifs

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I followed this answer to [Sans-serif math with latex in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013129/3183724) to get my matplotlib to use Computer Modern Sans. That works splendidly, except I can't get upright mu's to work. There's a ton of questions that go into that, but somehow I can't make it consistent with the above code.

What I'm using now is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True 
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}']
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'cm'
```

But when I try to do something like

```
plt.figure()
plt.text(0,0.5,r'$50 \mathrm{\mu m}$', size=16, c='k')
```

I just end up with a slanted mu. If instead I use \textmu, the character completely disappears and I get 50 m.

I tried doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709149/3183724) and then using \micro, but it just results in errors saying that that's an unknown symbol. Even though my MikTeX tells me siunitx is installed.

I'm sure this is just a silly mistake on my end, and I apologise if that is the case, but for the past 4 hours I have not been able to make any progress so I figured I would ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `upgreek` package, you could use `\upmu` to get an upright mu.

Unrelated to the problem, but I recommend the `siunitx` package to get propper spacing between numbers and units

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI{50}{\upmu m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that my problem was then somehow related to trying to get that \micro referenced in the second link I posted working. Upmu seems very well behaved. Thanks a lot! Also as a note for future readers, the upgreek package is part of a package called was.