# Why does Matplotlib not find Latex font?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I would like to use the Latex font in my Matplotlib diagrams. On Windows I have set the the system environment variable `PATH` to include the paths to MikTex's `bin\x64` folder, where the `latex` and `dvipdf` and `dvipng` scripts are located and to Ghostscripts `GS\BIN` folder.

However when I am trying to use the Latex font like this

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

I get an error message that the font was not found:

```
...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:1331: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I also tried deleting the Matplotlib cache, but I still get the same error.

What did I forget to do or what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: See my (admittedly old, hopefully not outdated) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537868/sans-serif-math-with-latex-in-matplotlib/20709149#20709149 . I think you need to work on a latex preamble. According to a comment on the post, specifically you need `\usepackage{helvet}`

Comment: Hi @PaulH, thanks for your comment! I now tried all of the three answers to other question (yours of course first ;-)), but I still get the `Font family ['sans-serif'] not found.` error. Do you have any other idea what could cause this issue?

Comment: is the font family simply "sans"?

Comment: (btw, with my old answer, you don't need to set the family)

Comment: I think the main issue was that I forgot to reset the rc settings using `mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)` so some previous issue kept messing up the whole thing.